# Questions about $B(H)$ and $B(H)/K(H)$ as Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

I am trying to investigate the relation between Uniformly Convexity and existence of Schauder Basis for a Banach space.

I read in a Handbook article  that $B(H)$ (the algebra of all bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$) and $B(H)/K(H)$ (the Calkin algebra for the same Hilbert space) are both naturally occurring examples of space which fails the Approximation Property.

I am wondering if we know:

a) if the above algebras are separable Banach spaces;

b) the convexity of them as Banach spaces (e.g. strictly convex, uniformly convex, ...?)

I apologize if this is really trivial functional analysis problem. Thank you!

Comment: I can't help mentioning that the Theorem: "B(H) fails the AP" is a highly non-trivial result of Szankowski (to which a whole [Acta 1981 paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02392870) is devoted). I think I've heard specialists would still like to understand this better and find an easier proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$B(H)$ [is not separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119264/separability-of-the-space-of-bounded-operators-on-a-hilbert-space) since it contains isometric copy of $\ell_\infty$ which [is non-separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75430/separability-of-l-infty?rq=1). $B(H)$ is not strctly convex since it contains isometric copy of $\ell_\infty$ which is [not strictly convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397329/proof-of-non-strictly-convexity-of-l-1-and-l-infty). A fortiori $B(H)$ is not uniformly convex because [every uniformly convex space is stricly convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space#Properties).

The same result holds for $C(H):=B(H)/K(H)$ since it [contains isometric copy of $\ell_\infty/c_0$](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAC&url=http://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/1301/1301-001.ps&ei=O5jUUYHPJe_a4QSHg4GoAw&usg=AFQjCNFDV61Rgy2zKokbpqwUQSC56d6jgQ&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bGE) which is not separable and not strictly convex.

Comment: Thanks Norbert - do you have a reference for the above results? I would like to get acquainted with such kinds of results~

Comment: @FanFeiChong some of them I just remember but I'll try to give references

Comment: @FanFeiChong I've added new referrences. If you wat I can write the  proof of non separability of $\ell_\infty/c_0$ but in a separate qestion.

Comment: Thank you! It is very helpful! Just one more question, how does one see that there is an isometric copy of $l_\infty$ in $B(H)$?

Comment: @FanFeiChong see edits to my answer

Comment: @FanFeiChong You can assume $H$ is infinite-dimensional separable. Then fixing an orthonormal basis, the bounded diagonal operators in that basis are isometric to $\ell^\infty$. And the compact ones are isometric to $c_0$.

Comment: Thanks again, Norbert and Julien!